# Excel Changes Dates into Numbers Automatically

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, date

Everytime I enter a date into a cell (e.g. 11/6/1989), Excel keeps changing it into a five or six digit number.  How can I get it to stop doing this?

Comment: Your cell is formatted as general or number,  Change the format to short date.

Comment: I tried formatting the cell/row and it won't change it

Answer (score 0):

The cell that you are trying to enter the date into is formatted wrong.  It depends on your version of Excel, but for the latest as of this writing (Excel 2016), you can change the cell's format to "Date" by following these steps:

1. Right click the cell.
2. Click "Format Cells..."
3. In the box labeled "Category", click the "Date" field.
4. Hit the "OK" button.

If this does not work for you, you can force Excel to display the date verbatim by adding an apostrophe (the ' character) before your data (like '11/6/1989).

Comment: I already tried that and its not working.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I am using excel 2010

Comment: Check my answer again for an alternate option.